# Finding out completed tasks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to show records based on a column completed_at. What is the best way to check at controller.task belongs to the user and user has_many tasks. Can I check based whether the column is nil or have some value?. Or any other best ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use not to check whether a column is not nil

```
Task.where.not(completed_at: nil)
```

or for user

```
user.tasks.where.not(completed_at: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use scope in the task model in rails 4,

```
scope :completed_task, ->{ where('completed_at IS NOT NULL') }
```

Now You can get all completed task of the user by

```
@user.tasks.completed_task
```